# Animate a div on scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm busy with my portfolio and i want to fadein a div when i scroll to the div called:

> Page2

Example:

[image]

When i am at the red page, the div called:

> image-wrapper

has to move..

I know how to animate, but not how to let it animate at an specific point.

I already tried it with an tutorial, but that didn't help :(

Thanks,

Comment: You have to show your code or make a fiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check if you are on `page2` or not. You can do this by checking which part of the page you are on by using `onscroll` event. You can check it by comparing `$(window).scrollTop()` and `elem.offset().top` or something similar.

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop()` gives you how much you have scrolled from top. Initially when you are at the top of the page it gives 0, and when you scroll, it gives you number of pixels you have scrolled. Now using this and the height of the window and the `top offset` of element, you can tell whether your desired element is visible or not. At the point it gets visible, you can do you animation or whatever you want to do.

Comment: So i have to do something like $(window).scrollTop('NameOfTheDiv')?

Comment: Nope.. You have to do something like `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#IdOFDiv').offset().top` to check if the div is inside the visible window.

Comment: Sorry my javascript sucks... This won't work: 

$(function(){
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#pagina2').offset().top
{
alert("hello");
}
}

Comment: Try This. `$(window).scroll(function(){ if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > $('#pagina2').offset().top) { alert("hello"); }} )`.

Comment: Thanks it works, but now everytime i scroll my div dissappears and appears ... CODE: $(window).scroll(function(){ if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > $('#pagina2').offset().top) { 

    var $d7 = $("#menuPage2");
    $d7.removeClass("p22");
    setTimeout(function(){$d7.addClass("p22")},1);

}

} 
)

Comment: Set it not visible at the time of page load. And in this code check if  it is visible or not. If it is already visible, don't make it fade in or visible again, just leave it.

Comment: How do you mean with visible, a own variable or what? :#

Comment: This doesn't work :(   :  $(window).scroll(function(){ if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > $('#pagina2').offset().top) { 
    var $active = "";
 if ( var $active === "Yes" )
 {
 
 }
 else
 {
 var $d7 = $("#menuPage2"); //little optimization because we will use it more than once
    $d7.removeClass("p22");
    setTimeout(function(){$d7.addClass("p22")},1);
 var $active = "Yes"
 }
 
}

Comment: `var active = false; $(window).scroll(function(){ if( !active && ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > $('#pagina2').offset().top) { alert("hello"); active = true }} )`

Comment: I would suggest you to first learn JS, Google a lot. And then, if anything does not work, ask something here.